# The triangle-sequence riddle

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

this is my number sequence:

> / - / - 1 - 2 - 7 - 6 - ?

This riddle has somtething to do with equilateral triangles
Good luck and have fun :)

PS: please tell me if this is too broad,
this is my first number-sequence level

Comment: Are these dashes intentional? Are they part of the puzzle? If not, what do they mean?

Comment: @WaisKamal They are part of the puzzle. They mean as you might think idk/not there/undefined

Comment: Another question, is this the start of the sequence or just a part of it?

Comment: @WaisKamal This is the start, mark a '1' over the first slash if you like

Comment: @WaisKamal wait ... did you mean with dash the hyphens or the slashes? Because i meant the slashes with idk/not there/undefined, the hyphons are just to seperate

Comment: Yeah I meant the slashes :)

Comment: @WaisKamal ohh goodness i had panic, having explained something wrong ... And? did you come to an idea, what could be meant?

Comment: Never came near, did an OEIS search and got 168 results :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85475/discussion-between-jannis-and-wais-kamal).

Comment: Is it a coincidence that 1 and 2 lines can't make equilateral triangles, 3 lines can make 1 and 4 lines can make 2? I can't get 7 triangles from 5 lines though, so my theory falls apart there :(

Comment: @Dmihawk well how would you do 5 lines with euilateral triagles? or 6 with 6?

Comment: Making 5 distinct lines? 3 triangles sharing a common line and alternating up/down. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Dmihawk what about connecting lines? 5 connected lines ... '-'

Comment: Posted in the chat thread

Comment: @Dmihawk how do I get there? I'm not experienced with chats...

Comment: Just the link you posted yesterday? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85475/discussion-between-jannis-and-wais-kamal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Answer**

The answer is:

> impossible? (or '/' as per the question)

Assuming

> The constructed shapes must only have acute interior angles, it is impossible to make a heptagon with equilateral triangles

An explanation is given by this picture

> [image: number_sequence_triangles]

**Original Guess**

I think the answer is:

> 8

Each number is in the sequence correlates to:

> The number of equilateral triangles required to build a shape which has the corresponding number of sides:
>
> 1 and 2-sided shapes with straight edges don't exist in 2D, hence the lack of values.
> A 3-sided shape takes 1 triangle (it's already a triangle :P )
> A 4-sided shape takes 2 triangles (a diamond)
> A 5-sided shape takes 7 triangles (an irregular pentagon)
> A 6-sided shape takes 6 triangles (a regular hexagon)
> A 7-sided shape can be made with 8 triangles, the next number in the sequence

Like so:

> [image: Triangle Solution]

Comment: You're close but not right.

Comment: Any closer? I'm outta answers if this one is wrong

Comment: I can tell you: the forms you drawed, except the last one are all correct

Comment: So my new assumption is wrong?

Comment: the last shape is incorrect. your logic has a fault

Comment: If you follow this logic, the 4th shape is wrong as well and rot13(pna or ohvyg jvgu) 4 rot13(gevnatyrf).

Comment: Yeah that's true, but the updated answer doesn't seem to be correct either

Comment: How about 5? And the logic is that it should be symmetrical

Comment: Using the 4th shape, just remove the middle triangle either on top or bottom and you have a 7-sided symmetrical shape

Comment: Updated answer - thanks @ImongMama :)

Comment: But a symmetric 6 sided one can be built using 4 - so I don't think that's the way to go.

Comment: Ooh. Oooooooooh

Comment: Thats not correct ... sry :( Tip: Try using polygons instead of x-sided-shapes

Comment: @Dmihawk I just see the your first Edit is actually a correct solution with correct logic, but formulated different

Comment: @Jannis: Do you want to hear that: rot13(Gurer vf ab frira-fvqrq pbairk funcr juvpu pna or ohvyg hfvat rdhvyngreny gevnatyrf.)

Comment: @beemaad Yes thats it, thats why the 5 sided shape is made with 7 and not with 5 triangles

Comment: So we got the right answer then...?

Comment: @Dmihawk seems so, I should mark this answer as correct, or do you make a new cleaner one?

Comment: I made the image at work, so I can't fix it until Monday. Might as well just mark the answer as is :)

Comment: @Dmihawk: I added a picture for additional explanations, if you don't mind...